# How to get users by last message in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently developing a simple chat application with Laravel 8 and VueJS. I need to order users by their latest message and get the last message along with the user. Below are the tables I am using if anyone has an idea for this operation. If it's an Eloquent method, it would be better.

**Users Table**

```
create table users
(
    id                        bigint unsigned auto_increment
    primary key,
    name                      varchar(255)                  not null,
    email                     varchar(255)                  not null,
    email_verified_at         timestamp                     null,
    password                  varchar(255)                  not null,
    two_factor_secret         text                          null,
    two_factor_recovery_codes text                          null,
    remember_token            varchar(100)                  null,
    status                    varchar(255) default 'online' not null,
    last_seen                 timestamp                     null,
    current_team_id           bigint unsigned               null,
    profile_photo_path        varchar(2048)                 null,
    created_at                timestamp                     null,
    updated_at                timestamp                     null,
    constraint users_email_unique
    unique (email)
)
collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**Private Messages Table**

```
create table private_messages
(
    id          bigint unsigned auto_increment
    primary key,
    sender_id   bigint unsigned not null,
    receiver_id bigint unsigned not null,
    message     varchar(1000)   not null,
    delete_type varchar(15)     null,
    created_at  timestamp       null,
    updated_at  timestamp       null,
    deleted_at  timestamp       null,
    constraint private_messages_receiver_id_foreign
    foreign key (receiver_id) references users (id)
    on delete cascade,
    constraint private_messages_sender_id_foreign
    foreign key (sender_id) references users (id)
    on delete cascade
)
collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Last message by sender and/or received? Which `{create|update|deleted}_at` fields do you want to base this on? Which MySQL server version?

Comment: I wanna get last message by eiter sender_id or receiver_id equals to authenticated user. And it can be base on created_at filed

Answer (score 0):

in user model create relation function

```
public function privateMessages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PrivateMessage::class)->orderBy('id','DESC');
}
```

then use

```
$users = User::with('privateMessages')->all();
```

in this result , messages sort by id desc.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Let's say John logged into his account and he gets the users list. In that list every user item has a last message. Last message means either John sent or received from the other user.